# After upgrade from SonarQube 4.5.4 LTS to 5.3, Ant analysis unable to delete files

Tags: ant, sonarqube, sonarqube5.3, sonarqube-scan

We recently upgraded from Sonarqube 4.5.4 LTS to 5.3.  After the upgrade, we've been encountering a problem with an analysis conducted via the SonarQube Scanner for Ant.

The relevant log error message:

```
...
Caused by: java.io.IOException: Unable to delete file: C:\build-dir\PUM-PUM30SONAR-JOB1\.sonar\cache\ff4174ae66dafc76b7dd3adbf9942334\sonar-pmd-plugin-2.5.jar_unzip\META-INF\lib\sslr-xpath-1.20.jar
```

The analysis conducted immediately prior to the SonarQube upgrade was fine.  Every execution after that has failed with this error.

So, it's like the build successfully creates this cache directory, but then when it tries to clean it up, it fails.  No issues reported by any builds using Maven or sonar-runner.

- Continuous Integration Application:  Bamboo 5.7.2
- Build Agents: Windows 2008 Server, happening on multiple agents
- Builds affected:only one confirmed, but maybe more
- SonarQube 5.3
- Ant 1.9.3
- SonarQube Scanner for Ant 2.4

What I have tried:

- verified that the Bamboo agent service is running as the correct user, and files can be deleted manually
- cleaned the build dir from the agent manually
- forced the build to run on an alternate agent

build.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<project name="POS Build" default="generate-installer">
    <property name="release.dir" value="release" />
    <property name="logs.dir" value="logs" />
    <property name="implementation.version" value="3.0.0.0.x"/>
    <property name="implementation.title" value="Redacted Module" />
    <property name="ia.home" value="${ia.home}" />

    <tstamp>
        <format property="today" pattern="d-MMMM-yyyy" />
    </tstamp>

    <target name="clean" description="Cleans up the build directory">
        <delete dir="${release.dir}" failonerror="no" />
        <delete dir="${logs.dir}" failonerror="no" />
        <delete dir="${basedir}/.sonar" failonerror="no"/>

    </target>

    <target name="init">
        <mkdir dir="${release.dir}" />
        <mkdir dir="${release.dir}/classes" />
        <mkdir dir="${release.dir}/drop" />

    </target>

    <target name="compile" depends="init">
        <javac classpath="${param_classpath}" srcdir="src" destdir="${release.dir}/classes" fork="true" />

        <copy todir="${release.dir}/classes" overwrite="true">
            <fileset dir=".">
                <exclude name ="resources/apache-ant-1.9.2-bin.zip" />
                <include name="resources/**" />
                <include name="work/**" />
            </fileset>

            <fileset dir ="src">
                <include name ="**/*.properties" />
            </fileset>
        </copy>
        <jar jarfile="${release.dir}/drop/pum.jar" basedir="${release.dir}/classes">

            <manifest>
                <attribute name="Created-By" value="${java.runtime.version}" />
                <attribute name="Built-On" value="${today}" />
                <attribute name="Implementation-Vendor" value="RedactedCompany Inc." />
                <attribute name="Implementation-Version" value="3.0.0.0.${build_no}" />
                <attribute name="Implementation-Title" value="${implementation.title}" />
            <!--    <attribute name="SplashScreen-Image" value="resources/images/splash.png" /> -->
                <attribute name="Main-Class" value="com.RedactedCompany.pos.pum.PUMApp" />
                <attribute name="Class-Path" value="${manifest_classpath}" />
            </manifest>
        </jar>

        <copy todir="${release.dir}/drop" overwrite="true">
            <fileset dir=".">
                <include name="resources/**" />
                <include name="lib/**" />
                <include name="work/**" />
            </fileset>
        </copy>

    </target>

    <target name="build" depends="init">

        <antcall target="clean" />

        <property name="project.classpath" value="
            lib/commons-lang3-3.1.jar;
            lib/jh.jar;
            lib/jsch-0.1.50.jar;
            lib/log4j-1.2.15.jar;
            lib/OfficeLnFs.jar;
            lib/opencsv-2.3.jar;
            lib/vim25.jar;
            lib/swingx-all-1.6.5-1.jar;
            lib/json-simple-1.1.1.jar;
            lib/balloontip-1.2.4.1.jar;
            lib/commons-validator-1.4.0.jar;
            lib/ini4j-0.5.2-SNAPSHOT.jar;
            lib/maven-artifact-3.0.5.jar;
            lib/selenium-java-2.45.0.jar;
            lib/selenium-server-standalone-2.45.0.jar;

        " />

        <property name="manifest.classpath" value="
            lib/commons-lang3-3.1.jar
            lib/jh.jar
            lib/jsch-0.1.50.jar
            lib/log4j-1.2.15.jar
            lib/OfficeLnFs.jar
            lib/opencsv-2.3.jar
            lib/vim25.jar
            lib/swingx-all-1.6.5-1.jar
            lib/json-simple-1.1.1.jar
            lib/balloontip-1.2.4.1.jar
            lib/commons-validator-1.4.0.jar
            lib/ini4j-0.5.2-SNAPSHOT.jar
            lib/maven-artifact-3.0.5.jar
            lib/selenium-java-2.45.0.jar
            lib/selenium-server-standalone-2.45.0.jar

        " />

        <antcall target="compile">
            <param name="param_classpath" value="${project.classpath}" />
            <param name="manifest_classpath" value="${manifest.classpath}" />
        </antcall>

    </target>
    <target name="generate-installer" depends="build" description="Generates the installer" >   
        <echo message="Start building the installer." />
        <taskdef name="buildinstaller" classname="com.zerog.ia.integration.ant.InstallAnywhereAntTask">
                <classpath>           
                    <pathelement location="${release.dir}/drop/lib/iaant.jar" />
                </classpath>
        </taskdef>    
      <buildinstaller IAlocation="${ia.home}" IAProjectFile="${basedir}/PUM3_0.iap_xml" BuildWindowsWithoutVM="false" BuildWindowsWithVM="true" BuildLinuxWithoutVM="false" BuildLinuxWithVM="true" BuildMergeModule="false" BuildReadOnlyMergeModule="false" OptimizeMergeModule="false" OptimizeWebInstaller="true" />
    <echo message="Finished building the installer." />      
    </target>


    <target name="sonar" depends="build">
    <path id="sonar.classpath">
    <fileset dir="${basedir}/lib" includes="**/*.jar" />
    </path>
     <taskdef resource="org/sonar/ant/antlib.xml" uri="antlib:org.sonar.ant" classpath="${basedir}/lib/sonarqube-ant-task-2.4.jar"/>


    <property name="sonar.userHome" value="${basedir}/.sonar"/>
    <property name="sonar.projectKey" value="com.RedactedCompany.redactedpart:pum:3.0.0" />
    <property name="sonar.projectName" value="${implementation.title}" />
    <property name="sonar.projectVersion" value="${implementation.version}" />
    <property name="sonar.projectBaseDir" value="${basedir}"/>
    <property name="sonar.sources" value="${basedir}/src"/>

    <property name="sonar.java.binaries" value="${release.dir}/classes" />
    <property name="sonar.java.libraries" value="${basedir}/lib/*.jar" /> 

    <property name="sonar.jdbc.url" value="jdbc:postgresql://sonar.forge.RedactedCompany.com/sonar" />
    <property name="sonar.jdbc.driver" value="org.postgresql.Driver" />

    <property name="sonar.host.url" value="http://sonar.forge.RedactedCompany.com/" />

     <sonar:sonar xmlns:sonar="antlib:org.sonar.ant">

     </sonar:sonar >

    </target>

</project>
```

cleansed Bamboo log:

```
simple  03-May-2016 02:43:17    Build PUM - PUM - PUM - PUMSONAR 3.0 - Sonar report #129 (PUM-PUM30SONAR-JOB1-129) started building on agent WIN-UFUHGNWD3QG
simple  03-May-2016 02:43:17    Build working directory is C:\build-dir\PUM-PUM30SONAR-JOB1
simple  03-May-2016 02:43:17    Executing build PUM - PUM - PUM - PUMSONAR 3.0 - Sonar report #129 (PUM-PUM30SONAR-JOB1-129)
simple  03-May-2016 02:43:17    Starting task 'Checkout Default Repository' of type 'com.atlassian.bamboo.plugins.vcs:task.vcs.checkout'
simple  03-May-2016 02:43:17    Running preRetrieveSourceCode task...
simple  03-May-2016 02:43:17    Updating source code to revision: 1011
simple  03-May-2016 02:43:17    Existing workspace found at 'C:\build-dir\PUM-PUM30SONAR-JOB1'. updating...
simple  03-May-2016 02:43:19    Updated source code to revision: 1011
simple  03-May-2016 02:43:19    Running postRetrieveSourceCode task...
simple  03-May-2016 02:43:19    Finished task 'Checkout Default Repository' with result: Success
simple  03-May-2016 02:43:19    Running pre-build action: VCS Version Collector
simple  03-May-2016 02:43:19    Running pre-build action: Clover Grails PreBuild Action
simple  03-May-2016 02:43:19    Starting task 'ANT Build' of type 'com.atlassian.bamboo.plugins.ant:task.builder.ant'
command 03-May-2016 02:43:19    Beginning to execute external process for build 'PUM - PUM - PUM - PUMSONAR 3.0 - Sonar report #129 (PUM-PUM30SONAR-JOB1-129)'\n ... running command line: TRUNCATED - AVAILABLE ON REQUEST
build   03-May-2016 02:43:19    Buildfile: C:\build-dir\PUM-PUM30SONAR-JOB1\build.xml
build   03-May-2016 02:43:20    
build   03-May-2016 02:43:20    init:
build   03-May-2016 02:43:20    
build   03-May-2016 02:43:20    build:
build   03-May-2016 02:43:20    
build   03-May-2016 02:43:20    clean:
build   03-May-2016 02:43:20       [delete] Deleting directory C:\build-dir\PUM-PUM30SONAR-JOB1\release
build   03-May-2016 02:43:20       [delete] Deleting directory C:\build-dir\PUM-PUM30SONAR-JOB1\.sonar
build   03-May-2016 02:43:20    
build   03-May-2016 02:43:20    init:
build   03-May-2016 02:43:20        [mkdir] Created dir: C:\build-dir\PUM-PUM30SONAR-JOB1\release
build   03-May-2016 02:43:20        [mkdir] Created dir: C:\build-dir\PUM-PUM30SONAR-JOB1\release\classes
build   03-May-2016 02:43:20        [mkdir] Created dir: C:\build-dir\PUM-PUM30SONAR-JOB1\release\drop
build   03-May-2016 02:43:20    
build   03-May-2016 02:43:20    compile:
build   03-May-2016 02:43:20        [javac] C:\build-dir\PUM-PUM30SONAR-JOB1\build.xml:57: warning: 'includeantruntime' was not set, defaulting to build.sysclasspath=last; set to false for repeatable builds
build   03-May-2016 02:43:21        [javac] Compiling 260 source files to C:\build-dir\PUM-PUM30SONAR-JOB1\release\classes
build   03-May-2016 02:43:27        [javac] Note: Some input files use or override a deprecated API.
build   03-May-2016 02:43:27        [javac] Note: Recompile with -Xlint:deprecation for details.
build   03-May-2016 02:43:27        [javac] Note: Some input files use unchecked or unsafe operations.
build   03-May-2016 02:43:27        [javac] Note: Recompile with -Xlint:unchecked for details.
build   03-May-2016 02:43:27         [copy] Copying 59 files to C:\build-dir\PUM-PUM30SONAR-JOB1\release\classes
build   03-May-2016 02:43:28          [jar] Building jar: C:\build-dir\PUM-PUM30SONAR-JOB1\release\drop\pum.jar
build   03-May-2016 02:43:29         [copy] Copying 72 files to C:\build-dir\PUM-PUM30SONAR-JOB1\release\drop
build   03-May-2016 02:43:29    
build   03-May-2016 02:43:29    sonar:
build   03-May-2016 02:43:29    [sonar:sonar] Apache Ant(TM) version 1.9.3 compiled on December 23 2013
build   03-May-2016 02:43:29    [sonar:sonar] SonarQube Ant Task version: 2.4
build   03-May-2016 02:43:29    [sonar:sonar] Loaded from: file:/C:/build-dir/PUM-PUM30SONAR-JOB1/lib/sonarqube-ant-task-2.4.jar
build   03-May-2016 02:43:30    [sonar:sonar] User cache: C:\build-dir\PUM-PUM30SONAR-JOB1\.sonar\cache
build   03-May-2016 02:43:34    [sonar:sonar] Load global repositories
build   03-May-2016 02:43:35    [sonar:sonar] Load global repositories (done) | time=421ms
build   03-May-2016 02:43:35    [sonar:sonar] Property 'sonar.jdbc.url' is not supported any more. It will be ignored. There is no longer any DB connection to the SQ database.
build   03-May-2016 02:43:35    [sonar:sonar] Property 'sonar.jdbc.username' is not supported any more. It will be ignored. There is no longer any DB connection to the SQ database.
build   03-May-2016 02:43:35    [sonar:sonar] Property 'sonar.jdbc.password' is not supported any more. It will be ignored. There is no longer any DB connection to the SQ database.
build   03-May-2016 02:43:35    [sonar:sonar] User cache: C:\build-dir\PUM-PUM30SONAR-JOB1\.sonar\cache
build   03-May-2016 02:43:35    [sonar:sonar] Load plugins index
build   03-May-2016 02:43:35    [sonar:sonar] Load plugins index (done) | time=5ms
build   03-May-2016 02:43:35    [sonar:sonar] Download sonar-cobertura-plugin-1.6.3.jar
build   03-May-2016 02:43:35    [sonar:sonar] Download sonar-cxx-plugin-0.9.5.jar
build   03-May-2016 02:43:36    [sonar:sonar] Download sonar-crowd-plugin-2.0.jar
build   03-May-2016 02:43:36    [sonar:sonar] Download sonar-pmd-plugin-2.5.jar
build   03-May-2016 02:43:37    [sonar:sonar] Download sonar-stylecop-plugin-1.1.jar
build   03-May-2016 02:43:37    [sonar:sonar] Download sonar-motion-chart-plugin-1.7.jar
build   03-May-2016 02:43:37    [sonar:sonar] Download sonar-scm-svn-plugin-1.3.jar
build   03-May-2016 02:43:37    [sonar:sonar] Download sonar-javascript-plugin-2.11.jar
build   03-May-2016 02:43:37    [sonar:sonar] Download sonar-csharp-plugin-5.1.jar
build   03-May-2016 02:43:38    [sonar:sonar] Download sonar-findbugs-plugin-3.3.jar
build   03-May-2016 02:43:38    [sonar:sonar] Download sonar-java-plugin-3.13.jar
build   03-May-2016 02:43:38    [sonar:sonar] Download sonar-scm-git-plugin-1.2.jar
build   03-May-2016 02:43:39    [sonar:sonar] Download sonar-xml-plugin-1.4.1.jar
build   03-May-2016 02:43:39    [sonar:sonar] Download sonar-php-plugin-2.8.jar
build   03-May-2016 02:43:39    [sonar:sonar] Download sonar-timeline-plugin-1.5.jar
build   03-May-2016 02:43:39    [sonar:sonar] Download sonar-build-breaker-plugin-2.0.jar
build   03-May-2016 02:43:39    [sonar:sonar] Download sonar-checkstyle-plugin-2.4.jar
build   03-May-2016 02:43:40    [sonar:sonar] Download sonar-jira-plugin-1.2.jar
build   03-May-2016 02:43:42    [sonar:sonar] Default locale: "en_US", source code encoding: "windows-1252" (analysis is platform dependent)
build   03-May-2016 02:43:42    [sonar:sonar] Process project properties
error   03-May-2016 02:43:43    
error   03-May-2016 02:43:43    BUILD FAILED
error   03-May-2016 02:43:43    C:\build-dir\PUM-PUM30SONAR-JOB1\build.xml:188: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Unable to load component class org.sonar.batch.scan.ProjectLock
error   03-May-2016 02:43:43        at org.sonar.core.platform.ComponentContainer$ExtendedDefaultPicoContainer.getComponent(ComponentContainer.java:62)
error   03-May-2016 02:43:43        at org.picocontainer.DefaultPicoContainer.getComponent(DefaultPicoContainer.java:678)
error   03-May-2016 02:43:43        at org.sonar.core.platform.ComponentContainer.getComponentByType(ComponentContainer.java:262)
error   03-May-2016 02:43:43        at org.sonar.batch.scan.ProjectScanContainer.doBeforeStart(ProjectScanContainer.java:109)
error   03-May-2016 02:43:43        at org.sonar.core.platform.ComponentContainer.startComponents(ComponentContainer.java:130)
error   03-May-2016 02:43:43        at org.sonar.core.platform.ComponentContainer.execute(ComponentContainer.java:117)
error   03-May-2016 02:43:43        at org.sonar.batch.task.ScanTask.execute(ScanTask.java:55)
error   03-May-2016 02:43:43        at org.sonar.batch.task.TaskContainer.doAfterStart(TaskContainer.java:86)
error   03-May-2016 02:43:43        at org.sonar.core.platform.ComponentContainer.startComponents(ComponentContainer.java:132)
error   03-May-2016 02:43:43        at org.sonar.core.platform.ComponentContainer.execute(ComponentContainer.java:117)
error   03-May-2016 02:43:43        at org.sonar.batch.bootstrap.GlobalContainer.executeTask(GlobalContainer.java:122)
error   03-May-2016 02:43:43        at org.sonar.batch.bootstrapper.Batch.executeTask(Batch.java:119)
error   03-May-2016 02:43:43        at org.sonar.runner.batch.BatchIsolatedLauncher.execute(BatchIsolatedLauncher.java:67)
error   03-May-2016 02:43:43        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
error   03-May-2016 02:43:43        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
error   03-May-2016 02:43:43        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
error   03-May-2016 02:43:43        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
error   03-May-2016 02:43:43        at org.sonar.runner.impl.IsolatedLauncherProxy.invoke(IsolatedLauncherProxy.java:61)
error   03-May-2016 02:43:43        at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy0.execute(Unknown Source)
error   03-May-2016 02:43:43        at org.sonar.runner.api.EmbeddedRunner.doExecute(EmbeddedRunner.java:274)
error   03-May-2016 02:43:43        at org.sonar.runner.api.EmbeddedRunner.runAnalysis(EmbeddedRunner.java:165)
error   03-May-2016 02:43:43        at org.sonar.runner.api.EmbeddedRunner.runAnalysis(EmbeddedRunner.java:152)
error   03-May-2016 02:43:43        at org.sonarsource.scanner.ant.SonarQubeTask.launchAnalysis(SonarQubeTask.java:72)
error   03-May-2016 02:43:43        at org.sonarsource.scanner.ant.SonarQubeTask.execute(SonarQubeTask.java:55)
error   03-May-2016 02:43:43        at org.apache.tools.ant.UnknownElement.execute(UnknownElement.java:292)
error   03-May-2016 02:43:43        at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor4.invoke(Unknown Source)
error   03-May-2016 02:43:43        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
error   03-May-2016 02:43:43        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
error   03-May-2016 02:43:43        at org.apache.tools.ant.dispatch.DispatchUtils.execute(DispatchUtils.java:106)
error   03-May-2016 02:43:43        at org.apache.tools.ant.Task.perform(Task.java:348)
error   03-May-2016 02:43:43        at org.apache.tools.ant.Target.execute(Target.java:435)
error   03-May-2016 02:43:43        at org.apache.tools.ant.Target.performTasks(Target.java:456)
error   03-May-2016 02:43:43        at org.apache.tools.ant.Project.executeSortedTargets(Project.java:1393)
error   03-May-2016 02:43:43        at org.apache.tools.ant.Project.executeTarget(Project.java:1364)
error   03-May-2016 02:43:43        at org.apache.tools.ant.helper.DefaultExecutor.executeTargets(DefaultExecutor.java:41)
error   03-May-2016 02:43:43        at org.apache.tools.ant.Project.executeTargets(Project.java:1248)
error   03-May-2016 02:43:43        at org.apache.tools.ant.Main.runBuild(Main.java:851)
error   03-May-2016 02:43:43        at org.apache.tools.ant.Main.startAnt(Main.java:235)
error   03-May-2016 02:43:43        at org.apache.tools.ant.launch.Launcher.run(Launcher.java:280)
error   03-May-2016 02:43:43        at org.apache.tools.ant.launch.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:109)
error   03-May-2016 02:43:43    Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Unable to load component class org.sonar.api.batch.bootstrap.ProjectReactor
error   03-May-2016 02:43:43        at org.sonar.core.platform.ComponentContainer$ExtendedDefaultPicoContainer.getComponent(ComponentContainer.java:62)
error   03-May-2016 02:43:43        at org.picocontainer.DefaultPicoContainer.getComponent(DefaultPicoContainer.java:632)
error   03-May-2016 02:43:43        at org.picocontainer.parameters.BasicComponentParameter$1.resolveInstance(BasicComponentParameter.java:118)
error   03-May-2016 02:43:43        at org.picocontainer.parameters.ComponentParameter$1.resolveInstance(ComponentParameter.java:136)
error   03-May-2016 02:43:43        at org.picocontainer.injectors.SingleMemberInjector.getParameter(SingleMemberInjector.java:78)
error   03-May-2016 02:43:43        at org.picocontainer.injectors.ConstructorInjector$CtorAndAdapters.getParameterArguments(ConstructorInjector.java:309)
error   03-May-2016 02:43:43        at org.picocontainer.injectors.ConstructorInjector$1.run(ConstructorInjector.java:335)
error   03-May-2016 02:43:43        at org.picocontainer.injectors.AbstractInjector$ThreadLocalCyclicDependencyGuard.observe(AbstractInjector.java:270)
error   03-May-2016 02:43:43        at org.picocontainer.injectors.ConstructorInjector.getComponentInstance(ConstructorInjector.java:364)
error   03-May-2016 02:43:43        at org.picocontainer.injectors.AbstractInjectionFactory$LifecycleAdapter.getComponentInstance(AbstractInjectionFactory.java:56)
error   03-May-2016 02:43:43        at org.picocontainer.behaviors.AbstractBehavior.getComponentInstance(AbstractBehavior.java:64)
error   03-May-2016 02:43:43        at org.picocontainer.behaviors.Stored.getComponentInstance(Stored.java:91)
error   03-May-2016 02:43:43        at org.picocontainer.DefaultPicoContainer.getInstance(DefaultPicoContainer.java:699)
error   03-May-2016 02:43:43        at org.picocontainer.DefaultPicoContainer.getComponent(DefaultPicoContainer.java:647)
error   03-May-2016 02:43:43        at org.sonar.core.platform.ComponentContainer$ExtendedDefaultPicoContainer.getComponent(ComponentContainer.java:60)
error   03-May-2016 02:43:43        ... 39 more
error   03-May-2016 02:43:43    Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to recreate working directory: C:\build-dir\PUM-PUM30SONAR-JOB1\.sonar
error   03-May-2016 02:43:43        at org.sonar.batch.scan.MutableProjectReactorProvider.cleanDirectory(MutableProjectReactorProvider.java:46)
error   03-May-2016 02:43:43        at org.sonar.batch.scan.MutableProjectReactorProvider.provide(MutableProjectReactorProvider.java:36)
error   03-May-2016 02:43:43        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
error   03-May-2016 02:43:43        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
error   03-May-2016 02:43:43        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
error   03-May-2016 02:43:43        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
error   03-May-2016 02:43:43        at org.picocontainer.injectors.MethodInjector.invokeMethod(MethodInjector.java:129)
error   03-May-2016 02:43:43        at org.picocontainer.injectors.MethodInjector.access$000(MethodInjector.java:39)
error   03-May-2016 02:43:43        at org.picocontainer.injectors.MethodInjector$2.run(MethodInjector.java:113)
error   03-May-2016 02:43:43        at org.picocontainer.injectors.AbstractInjector$ThreadLocalCyclicDependencyGuard.observe(AbstractInjector.java:270)
error   03-May-2016 02:43:43        at org.picocontainer.injectors.MethodInjector.decorateComponentInstance(MethodInjector.java:120)
error   03-May-2016 02:43:43        at org.picocontainer.injectors.CompositeInjector.decorateComponentInstance(CompositeInjector.java:58)
error   03-May-2016 02:43:43        at org.picocontainer.injectors.Reinjector.reinject(Reinjector.java:142)
error   03-May-2016 02:43:43        at org.picocontainer.injectors.ProviderAdapter.getComponentInstance(ProviderAdapter.java:96)
error   03-May-2016 02:43:43        at org.picocontainer.DefaultPicoContainer.getInstance(DefaultPicoContainer.java:699)
error   03-May-2016 02:43:43        at org.picocontainer.DefaultPicoContainer.getComponent(DefaultPicoContainer.java:647)
error   03-May-2016 02:43:43        at org.sonar.core.platform.ComponentContainer$ExtendedDefaultPicoContainer.getComponent(ComponentContainer.java:60)
error   03-May-2016 02:43:43        ... 53 more
error   03-May-2016 02:43:43    Caused by: java.io.IOException: Unable to delete file: C:\build-dir\PUM-PUM30SONAR-JOB1\.sonar\cache\ff4174ae66dafc76b7dd3adbf9942334\sonar-pmd-plugin-2.5.jar_unzip\META-INF\lib\sslr-xpath-1.20.jar
error   03-May-2016 02:43:43        at org.apache.commons.io.FileUtils.forceDelete(FileUtils.java:2279)
error   03-May-2016 02:43:43        at org.apache.commons.io.FileUtils.cleanDirectory(FileUtils.java:1653)
error   03-May-2016 02:43:43        at org.apache.commons.io.FileUtils.deleteDirectory(FileUtils.java:1535)
error   03-May-2016 02:43:43        at org.apache.commons.io.FileUtils.forceDelete(FileUtils.java:2270)
error   03-May-2016 02:43:43        at org.apache.commons.io.FileUtils.cleanDirectory(FileUtils.java:1653)
error   03-May-2016 02:43:43        at org.apache.commons.io.FileUtils.deleteDirectory(FileUtils.java:1535)
error   03-May-2016 02:43:43        at org.apache.commons.io.FileUtils.forceDelete(FileUtils.java:2270)
error   03-May-2016 02:43:43        at org.apache.commons.io.FileUtils.cleanDirectory(FileUtils.java:1653)
error   03-May-2016 02:43:43        at org.apache.commons.io.FileUtils.deleteDirectory(FileUtils.java:1535)
error   03-May-2016 02:43:43        at org.apache.commons.io.FileUtils.forceDelete(FileUtils.java:2270)
error   03-May-2016 02:43:43        at org.apache.commons.io.FileUtils.cleanDirectory(FileUtils.java:1653)
error   03-May-2016 02:43:43        at org.apache.commons.io.FileUtils.deleteDirectory(FileUtils.java:1535)
error   03-May-2016 02:43:43        at org.apache.commons.io.FileUtils.forceDelete(FileUtils.java:2270)
error   03-May-2016 02:43:43        at org.apache.commons.io.FileUtils.cleanDirectory(FileUtils.java:1653)
error   03-May-2016 02:43:43        at org.apache.commons.io.FileUtils.deleteDirectory(FileUtils.java:1535)
error   03-May-2016 02:43:43        at org.apache.commons.io.FileUtils.forceDelete(FileUtils.java:2270)
error   03-May-2016 02:43:43        at org.apache.commons.io.FileUtils.cleanDirectory(FileUtils.java:1653)
error   03-May-2016 02:43:43        at org.apache.commons.io.FileUtils.deleteDirectory(FileUtils.java:1535)
error   03-May-2016 02:43:43        at org.sonar.batch.scan.MutableProjectReactorProvider.cleanDirectory(MutableProjectReactorProvider.java:43)
error   03-May-2016 02:43:43        ... 69 more
error   03-May-2016 02:43:43    
error   03-May-2016 02:43:43    Total time: 23 seconds
simple  03-May-2016 02:43:43    Failing task since return code of [C:\ant\apache-ant-1.9.3\bin\ant.bat -Djava.io.tmpdir=c:\Users\forgeadmin\AppData\Local\Temp\PUM-PUM30SONAR-JOB1 -f build.xml sonar] was 1 while expected 0
simple  03-May-2016 02:43:43    Finished task 'ANT Build' with result: Failed
simple  03-May-2016 02:43:43    Running post build plugin 'Artifact Copier'
simple  03-May-2016 02:43:43    Publishing an artifact: Drop
simple  03-May-2016 02:43:43    Finished publishing of artifact Job artifact: [Drop], pattern: [release/drop/Default_Configuration/Web_Installers/InstData/] in 0s
simple  03-May-2016 02:43:43    Running post build plugin 'npm Cache Cleanup'
simple  03-May-2016 02:43:43    Running post build plugin 'NCover Results Collector'
simple  03-May-2016 02:43:43    Running post build plugin 'Clover Results Collector'
simple  03-May-2016 02:43:43    Finalising the build...
simple  03-May-2016 02:43:43    Stopping timer.
simple  03-May-2016 02:43:43    Build PUM-PUM30SONAR-JOB1-129 completed.
simple  03-May-2016 02:43:58    Running on server: post build plugin 'Clover Delta Calculator'
simple  03-May-2016 02:43:58    Running on server: post build plugin 'Build Hanging Detection Configuration'
simple  03-May-2016 02:43:58    Running on server: post build plugin 'NCover Results Collector'
simple  03-May-2016 02:43:58    Running on server: post build plugin 'Sonar Build Password Processor'
simple  03-May-2016 02:43:58    Running on server: post build plugin 'Maven Dependencies Postprocessor'
simple  03-May-2016 02:43:58    All post build plugins have finished
simple  03-May-2016 02:43:58    Generating build results summary...
simple  03-May-2016 02:43:58    Saving build results to disk...
simple  03-May-2016 02:43:58    Indexing build results...
simple  03-May-2016 02:43:58    Finished building PUM-PUM30SONAR-JOB1-129.
```

Comment: Ok, I think it actually is a file permission issue on the Bamboo agent.  When logged into the agent as the same user the agent process runs as, I get a "Server destination folder access denied.  You need to confirm this operation."  message, upon which I can click "Continue" and delete the file successfully.  I suspect this is interfering with the delete during the build.  No idea why this behaviour is coincident with the Sonar upgrade.  I'll try a few things with permissions/ownership.

Comment: I had the user repoint his build to our old 4.5.4 SonarQube test instance.  It worked fine.  He then pointed it back to SonarQube 5.3 and the build failed with the same error.  On the Bamboo build agent, I deleted the entire c:\build-dir tree, and recreated it using the ID running the Bamboo agent servers.  Same error.  I checked the "Effective Permissions" on the file noted in the error, and the Bamboo agent user has full permissions.  However, when attempting to delete the file manually, I still get the "Destination Folder Access Denied" message, which i need to click through.

Comment: I disabled UAC on the build agent.  Bamboo user is able to delete files without consenting to elevated admin access now.  Still getting error from the build.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

User included the following deprecated parameter, shown in the above build.xml:

```
<property name="sonar.userHome" value="${basedir}/.sonar"/>
```

Removal of this parameter allowed the build to proceed under SonarQube 5.3.